# Postgres query making high disk IO after upgrade to version 11

Tags: postgresql, query-optimization, postgresql-performance

Postgres query started talking high read IOPS and CPU after upgrade from RDS version 9.6 to RDS version 11.
The data set is same as it was before upgrade. Not sure what is the issue.

Below is the explain plan:

Could it be because index got corrupted?

```
Explain (analyze true, verbose true, costs true, buffers true, timing true )
select consumertr0_.ref_id as col_0_0_
from consumer_transactions consumertr0_
where (consumertr0_.remaining_amount is not null)
  and (consumertr0_.expiry_time is not null)
  and consumertr0_.expiry_time>'2020-12-15T00:00:00'
  and consumertr0_.expiry_time<now()
  and consumertr0_.remaining_amount>0
order by consumertr0_.expiry_time asc
limit 20000;

                  
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..80391.67 rows=20000 width=24) (actual time=191716.213..192077.229 rows=20000 loops=1)
   Output: ref_id, expiry_time
   Buffers: shared hit=9481343 read=1566736
   I/O Timings: read=97.486
   ->  Index Scan using consumer_transactions_expiry_time_remaining_amount on public.consumer_transactions consumertr0_  (cost=0.57..1109723.40 rows=276081 width=24) (actual time=191716.211..192075.241 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Output: ref_id, expiry_time
         Index Cond: ((consumertr0_.expiry_time > '2020-12-15 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (consumertr0_.expiry_time < now()))
         Buffers: shared hit=9481343 read=1566736
         I/O Timings: read=97.486
 Planning Time: 1.525 ms
 Execution Time: 192078.720 ms
(11 rows)
```

**index definition:**

```
"consumer_transactions_expiry_time_remaining_amount" btree
   (expiry_time, remaining_amount)
WHERE expiry_time IS NOT NULL
  AND remaining_amount IS NOT NULL
  AND remaining_amount > 0::numeric
```

**Analyze details:**

```
        relname        |         last_analyze          |       last_autoanalyze      
 consumer_transactions | 2021-01-24 22:00:03.144379+00 |
```

The same number of records had been processed earlier very quickly with low IOPS requirement. Though I do not have explain plan of previous version 9.6.

**Solution:**
I created same index with different name and it solved the issue. I ll drop old index once I identifies why suddenly old index became so slow right after upgrade.

Explain plan with new index:

```
explain (analyze true, verbose true, costs true, buffers true, timing true )  select consumertr0_.ref_id as col_0_0_ from consumer_transactions consumertr0_ where (consumertr0_.remaining_amount is not null) and (consumertr0_.expiry_time is not null) and consumertr0_.expiry_time>'2019-07-01T00:00:00' and consumertr0_.expiry_time<now() and consumertr0_.remaining_amount>0 order by consumertr0_.expiry_time asc limit 20000;

            
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Limit  (cost=0.57..73592.06 rows=20000 width=24) (actual time=0.048..18.307 rows=20000 loops=1)
   Output: ref_id, expiry_time
   Buffers: shared hit=11140
   ->  Index Scan using consumer_transactions_expiry_time_remaining_amount2 on public.consumer_transactions consumertr0_  (cost=0.57..22273478.26 rows=6053275 width=24) (actual time=0.047..16.119 rows=20000 loops=1)
         Output: ref_id, expiry_time
         Index Cond: ((consumertr0_.expiry_time > '2019-07-01 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (consumertr0_.expiry_time < now()))
         Buffers: shared hit=11140
 Planning Time: 1.160 ms
 Execution Time: 19.600 ms
(9 rows)

(END)
```

also older explain plan directly starts from actual time 191716.211 while new one starts with 0.047. I do not understand where is actual time spent before 191716.211.

FYI:
**index bloat details:**

```
 current_database | schemaname |        tblname        |                       idxname                       |  real_size  | extra_size  |    extra_ratio    | fillfactor | bloat_size  |    bloat_ratio    
| is_na 
------------------+------------+-----------------------+-----------------------------------------------------+-------------+-------------+-------------------+------------+-------------+-------------------
+-------
| f
 proddb            | public     | consumer_transactions | consumer_transactions_expiry_time_remaining_amount  |  4748820480 |  3698360320 |  77.8795563145819 |         90 |  3583516672 |  75.4611947765185 | f
 proddb            | public     | consumer_transactions | consumer_transactions_expiry_time_remaining_amount2 |  1755013120 |   704552960 |  40.1451676896866 |         90 |   589709312 |  33.6014190024973 | f
```

Comment: @Laurenz Albe: Please help here. Meanwhile I will try creating the same index again just in case it is an issue with index corruption.  I understand records fetched are quite high but the same no of records had. been fetch earlier as well, I have kept the same parameters changes.

Comment: Looks strange, like the table or the index are bloated. Does `REINDEX` or `VACUUM (FULL)` help?

Comment: Are you querying against a hot standby?

Comment: Do you have any long running transactions being held open?

Comment: @jjanes : I am running it on master (main primary) server. No long running transaction are being held open.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: Thanks a lot for prompt reply. I will test with creating another index on same fields with different name. drop older one. and then check query performance. I ll update you on it soon.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: I created another index with same fields and then ran the same queries. Queries were very fast and returned results in 20ms-200ms. old Index was bloated. But I do not understand how was this issue suddenly surfaced right after postgres ugprade. Also Please help me understand from the explain plan of old and new index... why old index was slow. Much appreciated. Adding the explain plan with new index on question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The old index was quite bloated: scanning it had to look at 11048079 8kB blocks (and read 1566736 of them from disk) to find the matching rows, while the new index had to look at only 11140 blocks.

I am not sure how the index got into this state.

The second index column seems pretty useless.

The perfect index for this query would be:

```
CREATE INDEX ON public.consumer_transactions (expiry_time) INCLUDE (ref_id)
WHERE remaining_amount > 0;
```

If you `VACUUM` the table, you would get a fast index-only scan.

Comment: old index is showing I/O Timings: read=97.486 which is 97 ms and is not much. so fetching from the disk shouldn't be an issue here. Also shared hit blocks are 6 times more than the blocks read from disk (shared hit=9481343 read=1566736) so it shared buffers would also take around 100ms... total time for old index scan= 97ms+ 100ms= 197ms but that is not reflecting in explain plan. why old explain plan is showing actual time=191716.211..192075.241. Also why node actual start time is at 191716.211? Where the ms before 191716.211 has gone?

Comment: Also what helped you think that index or table is bloated? also is there any way to check that out of total 100 index scan... 70% of index scan has happened from shared_buffers and rest of index scan has happened from disk.... just to know that index are not fitting in RAM and we need to do something about these. Thanks a lot @laurenz Albe

Comment: If you have to wade through 11 million index blocks to find 20000 rows, something is quite wrong with the index.

Comment: Thanks! would you please help me understand the actual time metric for index scan node for old index plan.

Comment: It took almost 200 seconds before the index scan found the first result.

Comment: Thanks, its very helpful :) Much appreciated!